# Output the array of integer values to screen in reversed order using recursion

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

```
void IntegerReversed(int* a, int n)
{
    if (n < 1) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        cout << a[n - 1] << endl;
        Integer(a, n - 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int* a;
    int n;
    cout << "Input n: ";
    cin >> n;
    a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0;i < n;i++) {
        cin >> *(a + i);
    }
    cout << "Integer values reversed in array: " << endl;
    IntegerReversed(a, n);
}
```

Hi this my code to output the array of integer values to screen in reversed order using recursion.

but it only prints the first correct element

Input : a[4]={1,2,3,4}

But output :
4 , 1 , 2 , 3

I want to print :
4 , 3 , 2 , 1
Can you help my fix this code

Comment: Fix the typo: `Integer(a, n - 1);` I'm guessing you have a function called `Integer` elsewhere in the code and you are calling that.

Comment: Your [mcve] is probably a bit better than your real code because it works (if you use `IntegerReversed` instead of `Integer` inside `integerReversed`). [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9mHd4S)

Answer (score 0):

i tested your program..

```
void IntegerReversed(int* a, int n)
{
    if (n < 1) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        cout << a[n - 1] << endl;
        IntegerReversed(a, n - 1);
    }
}
```

and this was just a spellling mistake..
in recursive call..

Comment: I know my error but i can't fix it . Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

While I get that this is probably an exercise in recursion itself, it's definitely not needed for this problem, since vectors (and most Standard Library containers) have built-in abilities to iterate in reverse.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  int numElements;
  std::cout << "Number of Elements: ";
  std::cin >> numElements;

  std::vector<int> arr(numElements);

  for (int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i) {
    std::cin >> arr[i];
  }

  for (auto rit = arr.rbegin(); rit != arr.rend(); ++rit) {
    std::cout << *rit << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```